# "App" has stopped android

Tags: java, android

Everytime I restart "app" from android studio, pop up "app" has stopped error.

Below is error messages

[image]

```
06-13 14:43:00.922 20338-20338/com.qh.qh2298:ipc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.qh.qh2298:ipc, PID: 20338
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.qh.qh2298-eb5idBCHvhKNut0740Cb8Q==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libRongIMLib.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
    at io.rong.imlib.NativeObject.<clinit>(NativeObject.java:8)
    at io.rong.imlib.NativeClient.init(NativeClient.java:132)
    at io.rong.imlib.LibHandlerStub.<init>(LibHandlerStub.java:45)
    at io.rong.imlib.ipc.RongService.onBind(RongService.java:31)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3431)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
06-13 14:43:01.930 1671-1688/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-13 14:43:02.330 20292-20292/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
06-13 14:43:02.331 20292-20292/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
06-13 14:43:02.374 20453-20453/? E//system/bin/webview_zygote32: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99093: Permission denied
06-13 14:43:02.374 20453-20453/? E/Zygote: createProcessGroup(99093, 0) failed: Permission denied
06-13 14:43:02.543 20477-20477/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted
06-13 14:43:02.711 20292-20483/com.qh.qh2298 E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
06-13 14:43:03.718 1671-2629/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
06-13 14:43:03.814 1399-1436/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Toast#0] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
06-13 14:43:03.816 20292-20380/com.qh.qh2298 E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
06-13 14:43:03.816 1399-1749/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [Toast#0] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
06-13 14:43:03.816 20292-20380/com.qh.qh2298 E/EGL_emulation: tid 20380: swapBuffers(550): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
06-13 14:43:03.819 1671-2629/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
06-13 14:43:04.025 1671-1688/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-13 14:43:04.158 1671-2629/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
06-13 14:43:04.200 1671-2629/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
06-13 14:43:05.757 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
06-13 14:43:05.758 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
06-13 14:43:05.940 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
06-13 14:43:05.941 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
06-13 14:43:05.979 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008a34
06-13 14:43:05.980 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008a34
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008073
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008073
06-13 14:43:05.981 20292-20503/com.qh.qh2298 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ff
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ff
```

Does anyone can tell me why this happened ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the `.so` files into jniLibs folder in `src/main`

[image]

Comment: Yes, this issue is relate to android simulator, only on simulator this error messages appear. But I didn't find .so files in  src/main folder.